# Java 2D Drawing Framework

Tags: java

Currently, I am using JHotDraw https://sourceforge.net/projects/jhotdraw/ as Figures Drawing Framework in my application.

> JHotDraw is a two-dimensional graphics
>   framework for structured drawing
>   editors that is written in Java. It is
>   based on Erich Gamma's JHotDraw, which
>   is copyright 1996, 1997 by IFA
>   Informatik and Erich Gamma.

I was wondering, besides JHotDraw, do you try out any Java 2D Drawing Framework, which is worth a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether any framework "is worth a try" is a judgment call. It is entirely subjective.

You can look at [G](http://geosoft.no/graphics/), a 2D library. Can't decided for you whether it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what needs to be done. Sometimes it is better to use raw Java 2D. Sometimes there is a need to use some markup language, so you can use such things as http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer// . Also there are some SVG 2 Java generators which can translate SVG file into java code, which will produce the same result using java 2d.

Answer (score 0):

Slick also is a 2d game(graphic) library : 
http://slick.cokeandcode.com/index.php